# How can I convert Linq to Entities Query into expression tree?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities, expression-trees

Say I have the following query how can I get the base Expression Tree?

```
MyContext.Items.Select(i=>i.Color);
```

I want to get the expression tree of this so that I can then use the expression tree to dynamically set what property is being selected (So I can choose Color, Size, Weight, Price etc.)

I think I am close with the following but I keep getting errors:

```
        IQueryable<Item> query = c.Items;


        string SelctField = "Color";
        ParameterExpression pe = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Item), "i");
        Expression SelectProperty = Expression.Property(pe, SelctField);

        MethodCallExpression Select = Expression.Call(
            typeof(Queryable),
            "Select",
            new Type[] {query.ElementType},
            pe,
            Expression.Lambda<Func<Item, string>>(SelectProperty, pe));

        var result =  query.Provider.CreateQuery<string>(Select);
```

The above results in

```
No generic method 'Select' on type 'System.Linq.Queryable' is compatible with the
supplied type arguments and arguments. No type arguments should be provided if the 
method is non-generic
```

so I tried removing that overload and just keep getting different errors.

I do also get this internal expression text in debug mode, but don't understand how to convert it.

```
    .Call System.Linq.Queryable.Select(
    .Call .Constant<System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[Inventory_Ordering_And_Reporting.Item]>(System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1[Inventory_Ordering_And_Reporting.Item]).MergeAs(.Constant<System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.MergeOption>(AppendOnly))
    ,
    '(.Lambda #Lambda1<System.Func`2[Inventory_Ordering_And_Reporting.Item,System.Nullable`1[System.String]]>))

    .Lambda      #Lambda1<System.Func`2[Inventory_Ordering_And_Reporting.Item,System.Nullable`1[System.String]]>(Inventory_Ordering_And_Reporting.Item $i)
{
    $i.Color
}
```

Comment: I might suggest having a look at this:
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx
 and this http://dynamiclinq.codeplex.com/

Comment: @AaronLS All they do is use expression trees anyways, for this perpose adding another dependency is overkill, especially when I can just use the exact same method they use anyways (at a much smaller scale)

Comment: I was more thinking you could look at the source of the Dynamic.cs and see how they did this programmatically.  There's an article specifically about expression trees here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882637.aspx

Comment: @AaronLS I have both looked at how they did it and also read your link article, a few times. And I still just can't get it right. I have added an attempt of my to my question. But I still can't wrapo my head around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not entirely sure if this will work with DB provider, but hopefully since it's purely expression based.

```
public class Item
{
    public string Blah { get; set; }
    public string Foo { get; set; }
}

[TestMethod]
public void Test()
{
    string propertyName = "Blah";
    System.Linq.Expressions.ParameterExpression arg = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Parameter(typeof(Item), "x");

    PropertyInfo pi = typeof(Item).GetProperty(propertyName,
    BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
    System.Linq.Expressions.Expression expr = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Property(arg, pi);
    System.Linq.Expressions.LambdaExpression lambda = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Lambda(expr, arg);
    System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<Item, string>> funcExpression = (System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<Item, string>>)lambda;

    List<Item> test = new List<Item> { new Item { Blah = "Test", Foo = "Another" } };
    IQueryable<Item> query = test.AsQueryable();
    var result = query.Select(funcExpression).ToList();
}
```

Comment: This works, is there a reason for the PropertyInfo part though? As when I run without that and replace your `pi` with the string containing the property name I want (as in my original example) it works.

Comment: Yeh, you are utilizing a different overload of .Property.  I honestly don't know if there is any benefit to using PropertyInfo, maybe in cases where you want more control over what properties are allowed to be dynamically selected(i.e. preventing a string containing the name of a private property).

Comment: Hopefully an easy solution, for your line `System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<Item, string>> funcExpression = (System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<Item, string>>)lambda;` is there any way to set the `string` portion of `Func<Item, string>` to be `pi.PropertyType` ??

Answer (score 1):

You could use reflection:

```
    public static void DoStuff(string fieldName)
    {
        List<test> ban = new List<test>();
        ban.Add(new test() { number = 40, notNumber = "hi" });
        ban.Add(new test() { number = 30, notNumber = "bye" });


        var result = ban.Select(item => item.GetType().GetField(fieldName).GetValue(item));
        foreach (var item in result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }
    class test
    {
        public int number;
        public string notNumber;
    }
```

This example is for fields the select should probably check to see if the field exists and if not then look for a property.

Comment: You can't use GetType, GetField, or GetValue in LINQ to Entities, this was the first thing I tried when I sought after the dynamic Select, but LINQ to Entities does not recognize them

Comment: This should work for in memory sets.  But I have a feeling it won't work for LINQ2SQL or 2Entities or any other DB provider.

Comment: I think what I found out was that LINQ 2... can only recognize a specific subset of methods, all are contained within [InsertDBNameHere]Functions Class, for example I can only use EntityFunctions Class methods. Only methods that linq can translate into SQL are supported.